# Recyclerview Retrofit 2 - How to display a new item after inserting to database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I'm working with RecyclerViewto display a list of comments and at the bottom (outside of the RecyclerView) I have a comment box to insert new comments to the list. I am able to insert the data to the database but I am clueless as to how to notify the adapter that a new comment has been added and to display it on the list.

All I'm trying to do is to display the new comment at the top of the list after it has been inserted to the database.

**Adapter**

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentsAdapter.CommentsHolder>{

private List<PostCommentsData> dataList;
private Context context;


public CommentsAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<PostCommentsData> commentsArrayList){
    this.dataList = commentsArrayList;
    this.context = applicationContext;
}

@Override
public CommentsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_post_comment, parent, false);
    return new CommentsHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CommentsHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(dataList.get(position).getComment_profile_image()).into(holder.ivProfileImage);
    holder.tvUserName.setText(dataList.get(position).getComment_username());
    holder.tvCommentDate.setText(dataList.get(position).getComment_datetime());
    holder.tvCommentBody.setText(dataList.get(position).getComment_body_text());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList == null ? 0 : dataList.size();
}

public static class CommentsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView ivProfileImage;
    TextView tvUserName;
    TextView tvCommentDate;
    TextView tvCommentBody;

    public CommentsHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        ivProfileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_profile_image);
        tvUserName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_username);
        tvCommentDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_date);
        tvCommentBody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
    }
  }
}
```

**Activity**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_comments);

    userSessionManager = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = userSessionManager.getUserDetails();
    userid = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_ID);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mPostID = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_ID);
    newCommentBox = findViewById(R.id.CommentBox);
    newCommentButton = findViewById(R.id.CommentSendButton);

    initCommentsView();
    submitNewComment();

    swipeContainer = findViewById(R.id.CommentsSwipeContainer);
    swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadComments();
        }
    });
}

private void initCommentsView(){
    rvPostComments = findViewById(R.id.post_comments_recyclerview);
    rvPostComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    postCommentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this, null);
    rvPostComments.setAdapter(postCommentsAdapter);
    rvPostComments.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    loadComments();
}

//This loads the comments list
private void loadComments(){

    String post_id = mPostID;
    postCommentsService = new PostCommentsService(this);
    postCommentsService.doGetPostComments(post_id, new Callback<PostCommentsList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostCommentsList> call, Response<PostCommentsList> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                commentsListData = response.body().getPost_comments_list();
                postCommentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), commentsListData);
                rvPostComments.setAdapter(postCommentsAdapter);
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            }else{
                //do error stuff
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            //do failure stuff
        }
    });
}

//This is the submit function for new comments.

public void submitNewComment(){
    newCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String newText = newCommentBox.getText().toString();
            String postID = mPostID;
            String userID = userid;

            postCommentsService = new PostCommentsService(PostCommentsActivity.this);
            postCommentsService.doAddNewComment(postID, userID, newText, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

                    PostCommentsData p = (PostCommentsData) response.body();
                    String msg = p.getMessage();

                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        if(!p.isError()){

                            //The message has been successfully added to the database.
                            //Now tell the adapter that there is a new comment and add it/show it on the list.
                            //How can this get done?

                        }else{
                            //do error stuff
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                    //do failure stuff
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

How can I update the list with the new comment (add it to the top) after I get the response from the server?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function in your adapter

```
public void addNewComment(PostCommentsData postCommentsData){
    this.dataList.add(0,postCommentsData);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

then when you add a comment in the database, call this function on the adapter object. `<adapter>.addNewComment(comment)`

```
PostCommentsData p = (PostCommentsData) response.body();
String msg = p.getMessage();
if (response.isSuccessful())
{
  if (!p.isError()) {
    postCommentsAdapter.addNewComment(p);

  } else {
    //do error stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Napster. I got the first part and added the function to the adapter but pardon my ignorance. I don't quite get where to place the function call and also, what does the (comment) part mean? where is "comment" coming from?

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! it works but the comment gets added at the bottom of the list instead of the top until I Swiperefresh the activity, then it shows at the top. Not sure if it matters but I have the query results ordered by date.

Comment: You can fix that by changing two lines. Look at my edited code for `addNewComment`

Comment: Outstanding. It works as excactly as needed. Thank you very much.